# Delete last "pair" from a some-pairs define-struct

Tags: recursion, racket

```
(define-struct make-no-pairs[])
(define-struct some-pairs[p ps])
```

This struct takes a "pair" (2 numbers) and a "pairs" (make-some-pairs[p ps])

example

```
(make-some-pairs (make-pair 10 10) (make-no-pairs))




(check-expect (any-undo (make-some-pairs 10 10 (make-no-pairs))) make-no-pairs)
```

How would I design the "any-undo" function to make this possible?

We are doing recursion and I am trying to make a big-bang animation that
creates a circle every time there is a mouse event and deletes the last circle
every time a key is pressed.

Thanks in advance! If you need more of my code to help me just comment and I will post the entire program.

Comment: I think you need to post what make-some-pairs does and what any-undo does

Comment: also why would you have a struct to represent no pairs can you not just use empty?

Answer (score 0):

One idea you can follow is to enforce some ordering. Always add to the end of the list or the front of the list, and always remove from the end of the list of the front of the list.

You could have your adding function do somethling like

```
(define (handle-click x y aworld)
  (... define logic to cons new (x, y) to front of
     your list of points in your world))

(define (handle-key akey aworld)
  (... define logic to remove the first element of the list
     of (x, y) in your world (should be very simple)))
```

Then just use them in your big bang function and it should just work :) I can add implementation details for these functions but I would need more info on the world you supply to big bang and your handle key/mouse functions

Also, I would argue "Some-pairs" should not be a structure on its own, but a part of your world which is just a list of pairs. Of course, this is without seeing all of your code.